# Installing MySQL Connector/C++ 

Tags: mysql, c++, ide

I would like to know which is the procedure to install the [mysql c++ connector](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp).

After installing it to my Ubuntu OS will I have these extra c++ commands avaiable in every c++ IDE? For example, can I use them in Qt, Netbeans, eclipse for c++ and all other c++ IDE environments after a successful installation?

Answer (score 12):

Using a debian command worked for me, but I haven't tested the libs yet, so I'm not 100% sure if it truly worked.  http://packages.debian.org/sid/libmysqlcppconn-dev

`apt-get install libmysqlcppconn-dev`

However, I did do this first https://askubuntu.com/a/259603/128334.   You probably will need to as well.

**Update (it works)**

I tried this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-cpp-examples-complete-example-1.html with this flag https://stackoverflow.com/a/11879650/1382306, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Goto command line and type :

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlcppconn-dev
```

Or if your are having some other issues you can go to the main website page :
[MySQL Connector Download](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/)
And download and build the connector yourself.

Comment: This post was answered already by user128334. How did you improve the previous answer @Subham Debnath with yours? I appreciate your enthusiasm as a `new contributor` but I am curious to know! Please explain.