# libapache2-mod-fastcgi "not available"

Tags: 12.10, apt, cgi

I've been here http://www.howtoforge.com/using-php5-fpm-with-apache2-on-ubuntu-12.10 and here http://www.versatilewebsolutions.com/blog/2012/11/installing-apache-2-with-php-fastcgi-on-ubuntu-12-10.html to try to install fastcgi on 12.10, but I keep getting

```
Package libapache2-mod-fastcgi is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libapache2-mod-fastcgi' has no installation candidate
```

I saw this https://serverfault.com/questions/395139/cant-install-fastcgi-ubuntu-server-package-libapache2-mod-fastcgi-is-not-availa but my `/etc/apt/sources.list` says

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main restricted universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-updates main restricted universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu quantal partner
```

Please help.  Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove `restricted` and add `multiverse`.

Once you do that, just follow the instructions.