# find & purchase restricted and multiverse for server?

Tags: server, apt, legal, restricted, multiverse

I stumbled upon [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/259603/128334) and enabled it on, a now shuttered, Ubuntu server.  I didn't know that [multiverse package are not completely free](https://askubuntu.com/a/58365/128334).

As in the question to the first answer:

1. How can a restricted/multiverse package be found?
2. How can those packages be purchased?

Comment: why dv?  i cannot find anything on it, and i'm still 99% noob

Comment: What are you looking for? where have you looked?

Comment: @SimplySimon i'm pretty sure I can find a package and maybe eventually figure out if it's restricted or multiverse, but I'd like to know the best way, and I really cannot find anything on buying those packages.

Comment: Have you searched the Internet (Google/Yahoo)? or the Ubuntu Software Centre?

Comment: @SimplySimon is that a trick question? ;))  this question's now #1 for "restricted multiverse purchase", and "restricted multiverse buy" has only 4 results.  for the package in the first linked question, it does show up in the Software Centre, but this is for server, so how do I purchase without a desktop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Free* here means *free as in freedom*, not *free as in free beer*. Non-free packages do not necessarily need to be purchased, but they put restriction on your freedom.

For example:

- `faac` (multiverse): this is an open-source library that lets you listen to FAAC audio files. The problem with the FAAC format is protected by patents. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FAAC):

  > Those intending to use this software module in hardware or software products are advised that this use may infringe existing patents.
- `nvidia-graphics-drivers-173` (restricted): this is one of the many nvidia drivers. The problem with them is that they are not open source, hence they can't be free software.

None of the packages in the restricted or multiverse repositories have a price.

By the way, Ubuntu offers software for purchase, but you can get it only with the Ubuntu Software Center, not with the official repositories.

Comment: wow, that's sad.  looks like i'll be avoiding everything restricted/multiverse.  ty!

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to revise your installed packages from the point of view of free software, I recommend using the `vrms` (*"virtual Richard M. Stallman"*) tool (included in the standard repositories) - just install it and run as simply as

```
vrms
```

Good luck with freeing your system! ;)